# Docker image size and how much space should I expect 'dnu restore' to take up?

Tags: docker, asp.net-core

I have a dockerized asp5 web api project that's image takes up around 918 MB of disk space. I know that, due to the nature of docker, images can get quite big but 600 MB added to the original aspnet5 image from my quite small app seems a tad excessive. Specifically the `dnu restore` step in my Dockerfile adds around 500MB to the size of my image. Am I going to have to live with this or is there something I can do to reduce the size?

Here is my project.json:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "compilationOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true
  },

  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNet.IISPlatformHandler": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileProviderExtensions" : "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0-rc1-final"
  },

  "commands": {
    "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting --server Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel --server.urls http://*:5000"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "dnx451": { },
    "dnxcore50": {
      "dependencies": {
        "System.Diagnostics.Process": "4.1.0-beta-23409"
      }
    }
  },

  "exclude": [
    "wwwroot",
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "publishExclude": [
    "**.user",
    "**.vspscc"
  ]
}
```

I think the only think I added on top of the standard VS template for a Web API project is the line `"System.Diagnostics.Process": "4.1.0-beta-23409"`
Thanks a lot for any help you can provide. 
Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM microsoft/aspnet:1.0.0-rc1-final-coreclr

RUN apt-get -qq update \
    && apt-get -qqy install nano postgresql-client s3cmd \
    && apt-get -y autoremove \
    && apt-get -y clean \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

COPY . /app

WORKDIR /app
RUN ["dnu", "restore"]


EXPOSE 5000

ENTRYPOINT ["dnx", "-p", "project.json", "web"]
```

And here is my `docker history` for the image

```
IMAGE               CREATED              CREATED BY                                      SIZE                COMMENT
4ee2fb3cb020        35 seconds ago       /bin/sh -c #(nop) ENTRYPOINT &{["dnx" "-p" "p   0 B
24009ffd82e6        38 seconds ago       /bin/sh -c #(nop) EXPOSE 5000/tcp               0 B
9c46bb3859e9        51 seconds ago       dnu restore                                     526.6 MB
d536b68081ba        About a minute ago   /bin/sh -c #(nop) WORKDIR /app                  0 B
4f19849eea0a        About a minute ago   /bin/sh -c #(nop) COPY dir:cb4b00a5061a16f1f6   684.6 kB
b640bd0c52a2        2 days ago           /bin/sh -c apt-get -qq update                   && apt-get -qq      36.37 MB
8fa640275ee6        2 days ago           /bin/sh -c #(nop) ENV PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/u   0 B
e4f675d032df        2 days ago           /bin/sh -c LIBUV_VERSION=1.4.2                  && apt-get -q       2.406 MB
385c0bace97d        2 days ago           /bin/sh -c bash -c "source $DNX_USER_HOME/dnv   49.22 MB
7c9fafa077c3        2 days ago           /bin/sh -c curl -sSL https://raw.githubuserco   44.04 kB
2ae394ac9389        2 days ago           /bin/sh -c apt-get -qq update && apt-get -qqy   178.1 MB
b07742e812ff        2 days ago           /bin/sh -c #(nop) ENV DNX_RUNTIME_ID=ubuntu.1   0 B
e7d3e76b41ad        2 days ago           /bin/sh -c #(nop) ENV DNX_USER_HOME=/opt/DNX_   0 B
d0ee80de6cbb        2 days ago           /bin/sh -c #(nop) ENV DNX_VERSION=1.0.0-rc1-f   0 B
ea6bab360f56        7 days ago           /bin/sh -c #(nop) CMD ["/bin/bash"]             0 B
5679b9b90e09        7 days ago           /bin/sh -c #(nop) ADD file:5afd8eec1dc1e7666d   125.1 MB
```

Comment: It might be helpful to post a `Dockerfile` for others to try and reproduce. But at first glance the `microsoft/aspnet` image is already around 750mB. A good way of narrowing down the particular `Dockerfile` command and layer that is adding bloat is `docker history`, which will show you each layer, size, and command that was used to build it.

Comment: @AndyShinn I have now posted my dockerfile. My `docker images` lists microsoft/aspnet image as being 354MB

Comment: Also thanks. Never used `docker history` before and that looks really useful

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another approach you can take is to publish the app and then make the published app as part of the Docker image:,

Example: Here I would like to run my app only on Core Clr

- Run `dnu publish --framework dnxcore50 --out ../publishedoutput` (Here I explicitly specify `framework` as your app could be targeting both `dnx451` and `dnxcore50` and since you are sure you want to run on Core Clr, you can avoid packaging `dnx451` related packages...so that's a reduction in image size)
- A docker file which can be used against the above the published directory to create the docker image.

  ```
  FROM microsoft/aspnet:1.0.0-rc1-final-coreclr
  COPY . /app/
  WORKDIR /app/approot
  EXPOSE 5004
  ENTRYPOINT ["./kestrel"]
  ```

More info:
Restored packages size is **NOT** the same as published packages of an application.
You can understand why this is the case by opening up the restored packages...For example, in the below scenario the published package has only the required content for running the application.

**Restored** JSON.NET package content:
[image]

**Published** JSON.NET package content:
[image]

Comment: Ahhhhh this explains quite a bit. Thank you. I will definitely look into publishing rather than restoring.

Comment: Yeah publishing was the way to go. Reduced my image size by around 470MB. Thanks a lot